# RabbitMQ lock message group

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

I'm seeking help from RabbitMQ or other message broker user professionals. I'm relatively new into message broker systems so please bear with me, if i'm not using the correct wording.

We have a SAAS platform where users signup, and we start to automate some processes for them. Some of these processes needs to handled on-by-one for each user. This is where we would like to use message broker.

The system is illustrated here:

[image]

Where we colors indicates different users. So if C-1 start to process the first task from yellow-user, C-2 must take the task from blue-user.

Suggestion 1:

[image]

Is it possible to "lock" a group of tasks when a consumer starts to handle a task from a specific group? In this case C-2 should then take the blue-user task. Scaling the number of consumers would be rather straightforward here.

Suggestion 2:

[image]

Here each user has its own queue, with one consumer attached. The challenge for us here is, how do we start a consumer automatically when a new queue is created and possibly stop the consumer if the queue i not used for a while?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use rabbitmq, you should use the Suggestion 2, there's no way to 'lock' messages in a queue by some key. The closest are priorities, and it does not fit your model.

Using the Suggestion 2 approach requires you to declare the queue before sending a message to it (or controlling the declaration in another way, since there's no auto-creation for queues in RabbitMQ) and using the [queue TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#queue-ttl). You should also consider [exclusive queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#exclusive-queues) as an alternative, where the queue creation is controlled by the consumer instead of the publisher.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is it correct understood that queue ttl is first considered when the consumer is disconnected? My challenge with Suggestion 2 is the whole structural part of starting consumers on new queues, how to make sure they not run forever, start a new consumer if ttl is invoked, start new consumers for all if the server breaks down. Do you know any good-practice reading for these type of topics?

Comment: @MadsMønster Yes, that's correct. I think that if you want to use RMQ for this, you need to shift the logic from the broker to the consumers in your model. I fear I can only point you to Kafka, from what I've heard, it may suit your needs more than RMQ (but take this with a grain of salt, I've never used Kafka before)

Comment: @MadsMønster did you find a way to implement it?

Comment: @melih I do not have a prod ready solution yet, but my current solution is to use rabbitmq_event_exchange and have a consumer that start at consumer on the new queue and check if the queue is empty. If the queue is empty for a period of time, it will delete the queue

Comment: @MadsMønster how do you start consumers for new queues?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the routing key the user id then you can use the consistent hash exchange to shard the messages by that key. Bind a few queues to that exchange and the messages of any given user id will exist in only a single queue. Then get c1 to subscribe to queue1, c2 to queue2 etc. You can also enable Single-Active-Consumer (SAC) on each of the queues to ensure that only a single consumer is connected to each queue at a time.

You'll need version 3.8 and onwards if you want SAC.